# html5 canvas strokeStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I am trying to map an image to a "3d" grid that simulates cloth using strokeStyle and canvas, i have the image included but it is currently acting as a background image and not actually flowing with the "cloth" as is ripples, I.E the image is static as the grid flows.
here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7nBq/) which is self explanatory ( only works in Chrome). 
any help is much appreciated.
here is the javascript that renders the image into the background, How do i stop from rendering as a background image and only make it fill the grid?:

```
function update() {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://free-textures.got3d.com/architectural/free-stone-wall-   textures/images/free-stone-wall-texture-002.jpg';
    img.onload = function() {

        // create pattern
        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        physics.update();

        ctx.strokeStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.beginPath();
        var i = points.length;
        while (i--) points[i].draw();
        ctx.stroke();

        requestAnimFrame(update);
    }
}
```

Hers's the original [codepen](http://codepen.io/stuffit/pen/KrAwx) I'm working from.
    `updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7nBq/) with image outside function update():
It currently seems to actually fill the cells as well as applying it as a background image. is there any way to stop it becoming a background image and only apply it to fill the grid? I've tried this:
   ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
and removing line 260:
ctx.strokeStyle = ptrn;
but it  seems to remove the background image just displaying it as a black grid... thank you again for the patience

Comment: no I don't expect any one to debug the wall of code my exact question is:
How do i map the image to the grid, function update() {

 var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'file:///C:/Users/CL%20Ceintuurbaan/Desktop/texture_2.jpg';
  img.onload = function(){
 
    // create pattern
    var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');

 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 physics.update();
  
 ctx.strokeStyle = ptrn;
 ctx.beginPath();
 var i = points.length;
 while(i--) points[i].draw();
 ctx.stroke();

 requestAnimFrame(update);
 
  }
}
Is the function dealing with the image rendering.

Comment: let me edit the question sorry for the inconviniance.

Comment: OK, I get it. But I'm afraid you'll have to make one `drawImage` per cell of your wall.

Comment: Note that I get a much faster animation by not initializing the image in the update function : http://jsfiddle.net/MdbLB/.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, it currently seems to actually fill the cells as well as applying it as a background image. is there any way to stop it becoming a background image and only apply it to fill the grid? I've tried this:  
   ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
but it doesn't seem to remove the background image. thank you again for the patience

Comment: Thanks your completely right that is a lot smoother.

Comment: I would probably attach a small image to each point, and draw it from the point draw method, based on the constraints. But you'll have some work to do it.

Comment: do you have an example to start from? I'm guessing you mean here:
`while(i--) points[i].draw();`

Comment: Note: I also don't mind losing the actual grid if the image could maintain cloth like properties.

Comment: I have no example, sorry. Cutting the big image in small images and attaching them to points is straightforward (and boring). Drawing the small images according to constraints might be a little harder especially when the number of constraints per point isn't 4. There probably is some standard practice here but I don't know it (should webgl be used ?).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Oh my! Great question!

So let's see what we've got. A system that has a bunch of "constraints", which are sets of 2 points. Contraints themselves come in pairs, and they make two lines, forming  a `┘` shape (the bottom-right of a box).

If we were to draw every constraint line individually we'd see this:

[image: boxes!]

That's all horizontal red lines and vertical blue lines. Drawing a single one we'd just see that `┘` shape, and each long red line is really hundreds of little lines, the bottom of each `┘` shape, end to end.  There are several hundred `┘`s here, and together they make it look like a cohesive mesh. The fact that each one is already individual makes this easy for us.

That shape is all we need to determine a sort-of bounding box. And it looks like each `Point` in a `Constraint` comes with original values, so we'll save those as `sx` and `sy`.

If we know the bounds of the boxes at their new location, and we know the original bounds beecause we've saved all the Point's values for the Contraints, then we should be golden.

Once we have the original bounding box of a Constraint and its current bounding box, why, all we have to do is call drawImage with both boxes: `ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);`

I wrote a new `Constraint.prototype.draw` routine, It looks like this:

[image: yeah!]

[image: more yeah!]

And so on.

There are a few ways you could "patch" the holes, and its really up to you, otherwise you'll have to finagle with transformations.

Have a look at the code. I didn't change much. Look for `!!!` in the code (my edits) and `DEBUG:` in the code (debug code in case the image does not load or you wanna see the wireframes).

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/Kuw6P/

The code is long so I don't wanna paste it all here, but here's a backup in case jsfiddle goes down: https://gist.github.com/simonsarris/5405304

And here's the most relevant part:

```
// !!! new super awesome draw routine! So cool we skipped naming it draw2!
Constraint.prototype.draw3 = function(otherP2) {

  // NOW dear friends consider what we have. Each box is made out of two lines,
  // the bottom and rightmost ones.
  // From these lines we can deduce the topleft and bottom-right points
  // From these points we can deduce rectangles
  // From the skewed rectangle vs the original rectangle we can "stretch"
  // an image, using drawImage's overloaded goodness.

  // AND WE'RE OFF:

  // destination rect has 2 points:
  //top left: Math.min(this.p2.x, otherP2.x), Math.min(this.p2.y, otherP2.y)
  //bottom right: (this.p1.x, this.p1.y)

  // image destination rectangle, a rect made from the two points
  var dx = Math.min(this.p1.x,  Math.min(this.p2.x, otherP2.x));
  var dy = Math.min(this.p1.y,  Math.min(this.p2.y, otherP2.y));
  var dw = Math.abs(this.p1.x - Math.min(this.p2.x, otherP2.x));
  var dh = Math.abs(this.p1.y - Math.min(this.p2.y, otherP2.y));
  // DEBUG: IF THERE IS NO IMAGE TURN THIS ON:
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'lime';
  //ctx.strokeRect(dx, dy, dw, dh);

  // source rect 2 points:
  //top left: Math.min(this.p2.sx, otherP2.sx), Math.min(this.p2.sy, otherP2.sy)
  //bottom right: (this.p1.sx, this.p1.sy)

  // these do NOT need to be caluclated every time,
  // they never change for a given constraint
  // calculate them the first time only. I could do this earlier but I'm lazy
  // and its past midnight. See also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwaQxDkpcHY#t=64s
  if (this.sx === undefined) {
    this.sx = Math.min(this.p1.sx,  Math.min(this.p2.sx, otherP2.sx));
    this.sy = Math.min(this.p1.sy,  Math.min(this.p2.sy, otherP2.sy));
    this.sw = Math.abs(this.p1.sx - Math.min(this.p2.sx, otherP2.sx));
    this.sh = Math.abs(this.p1.sy - Math.min(this.p2.sy, otherP2.sy));
  }
  var sx = this.sx;
  var sy = this.sy;
  var sw = this.sw;
  var sh = this.sh;
  // DEBUG: IF THERE IS NO IMAGE TURN THIS ON:
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  //ctx.strokeRect(sx, sy, sw, sh);


  // IF we have a source and destination rectangle, then we can map an image
  // piece using drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
  // Only problem, we're not exactly dealing with rectangles....
  // But we'll deal. Transformations have kooties anyways.
  ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
};
```